# Iterating through an array of objects to filter specific data

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get specific data filtered on an API call. The objects are not iterable and I have tried a million different ways to get the specific data I need.

So...I need to filter out `tip_money` and return only that data instead of the full response.

Here is the call

```
router.get('/', auth, (req, res) => {
    try {
        apiInstance.listPayments(opts).then(function (payments) {
            res.send(payments)
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
});
```

and here is the response (partially):

```
{
    "payments": [
        {
            "id": "rt6Q8LL3XrCLGltl3bBhazMF",
            "created_at": "2019-11-12T23:34:03.012Z",
            "updated_at": "2019-11-12T23:53:45.481Z",
            "amount_money": {
                "amount": 13080,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "total_money": {
                "amount": 14047,
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "processing_fee": [
                {
                    "effective_at": "2019-11-13T01:53:44.000Z",
                    "type": "INITIAL",
                    "amount_money": {
                        "amount": 375,
                        "currency": "USD"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "status": "COMPLETED",
            "source_type": "CARD",
            "card_details": {
                "status": "CAPTURED",
                "card": {
                    "card_brand": "VISA",
                    "last_4": "",
                    "exp_month": ,
                    "exp_year": ,
                    "cardholder_name": "",
                    "fingerprint": "",
                    "bin": ""
                },
                "entry_method": "EMV",
                "cvv_status": "CVV_NOT_CHECKED",
                "avs_status": "AVS_NOT_CHECKED",
                "auth_result_code": "009208",
                "application_identifier": "A0000000031010",
                "application_name": "CITI VISA",
                "application_cryptogram": "6b7992ab9fba75fe",
                "verification_method": "SIGNATURE",
                "verification_results": "UNKNOWN",
                "statement_description": ""
            },
            "location_id": "",
            "order_id": "",
            "employee_id": "DrU-af4--DVfMCkl2z73"
        },
```

any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Why isn't it iterable? Iterate through the `object.payments` array, and test if the element has a `tip_money` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if something like this works for you

```
router.get('/tips', auth, (req, res) => {
    try {
        apiInstance.listPayments(opts).then(function (payments) {
            const tips = payments.map(payment => payment.tip_money).filter(tip => tip != undefined);
            res.send(tips);
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
});
```

Remove the .filter at the end if you also want the endpoint to return the undefined tips since it doesn't seem like all the payments have tips on them.

Comment: getting this error `(node:55174) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: payments.map is not a function`

Comment: Isn't payments referring to the whole object? Using that name for the variable you'd write `payments.payments.map ...`. And you could also do the filtering before the mapping, like `.filter(payment => "tip_money" in payment).map(payment => payment.tip_money)`.